# How many URLs can be handled by using Scrapy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a file containing many URLs. I am willing to extract the links from those URLs and then extract the title and metas of the different pages.

I want to know how many URLs can be fed to the Scrapy crawler, so that I get the appropriate result. I do not know whether Scrapy will have any limitation of URL scanning and extracting links from the URLs. How can I randomize the extracted links?

```
le = LinkExtractor()
for link in le.extract_links(response):
    yield scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.parse_inof)
```

See the above code. I am using this to extract links from the URL. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CONCURRENT_ITEMS
Default: 100
```

Maximum number of concurrent items (per response) to process in parallel in the Item Processor (also known as the Item Pipeline).

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS
Default: 16
```

The maximum number of concurrent (ie. simultaneous) requests that will be performed by the Scrapy downloader

Edit;
Altso, might be possible to use,

```
import random

list = [20, 16, 10, 5];
random.shuffle(list)
print "Reshuffled list : ",  list

random.shuffle(list)
print "Reshuffled list : ",  list

You might need to give the list urls a numeric id first.
```

Comment: I tried `random`. but I don't know it doesn't work in my case. I am still looking for the reason.

Comment: Also is there any limit on the url handling? I have crores of url.

Comment: have you tried 

rand_item = random.choice(items)?

if you set
CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT to 0 it will continue forever while there is memory or no exception

Comment: Good thought let me try it

Comment: When I try `random.shuffle` I get the following error `  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 288, in shuffle`
    `for i in reversed(xrange(1, len(x))):`
`TypeError: object of type 'LxmlLinkExtractor' has no len()`

Comment: Ok, it might seem like you are shuffeling between le objects, and that is not a recongnizeable list object I guess, so you will probably need to insert urls to a new list in the for loop and then do a new for loop with random on that new list (prob not the right way though)